# Convert date to persian date in lambda linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda

I want to change my save date in SQL to a persian date. I use linq this my code but I have error for milladi2shamsi class

```
public string Miladi2Shamsi(DateTime _date)
{
        PersianCalendar p = new PersianCalendar();
        DateTime dmiladi = new DateTime();
        DateTime sp = new DateTime();
        dmiladi = _date;

        sp = Convert.ToDateTime
            (p.GetYear(dmiladi).ToString() + " " + p.GetMonth(dmiladi).ToString() 
            + " " + p.GetDayOfMonth(dmiladi).ToString() + " " 
            + p.GetDayOfWeek(dmiladi).ToString() + " ");

        return sp.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
    }
```

This is my class for change date to persian date date save in sql miladi date

```
var q = db.Kharidars.Join(db.Factor_kharidars, c => c.Id, o =>
               o.Id_kharidar_bes, (c, o) => new
               {
                   o.Row,
                   c.Coname,
                   Miladi2Shamsi(o.Date),
                   o.Id_kharidar
               })Where(i => i.Id_kharidar
               == Guid.Parse(txtid.Text)).Where(i => i.Date >= Convert.ToDateTime(datenow.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")));
```

Comment: What is the error? Where exactly in your code is it happening? Have you researched the error and made an effort to understand what it is and why it is happening? Have you attempted to fix it already? If so, what have you tried?

Comment: What is the error you're experiencing?

Comment: Which error? BTW move `Guid.Parse()` **outside** your LINQ query. Just drop `Convert.ToDateTime()` because you don't need it. Fixed that you have to remove `Miladi2Shamsi` call. It can't be translated in SQL. Do that **after** you queried DB. I think it's just a presentation problem, right?

Comment: As I'm not a native speaker of whatever language this code is written in (e.g. `Kharidar`), I'm not entirely sure what it's doing. However, you should be using the `DateTime.ToString(string, IFormatProvider)` method to properly format your dates into the appropriate format using the relevant Persian `CultureInfo` and format string.  All storage inside SQL Server itself should really be in the invariant format, with culture-specific formatting done client-side.

Comment: You also don't seem to have a very good understanding of what a class is. `Miladi2Shamsi` is a method, not a class.  Your second code snippet is also not a class.

Comment: I'd also strongly advise against all these pointless string conversions. There's no need to call `Convert.ToDateTime` *at all* as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your function to this:

```
public string Miladi2Shamsi(DateTime _date)
{
    PersianCalendar p = new PersianCalendar();

    string sp = string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}",
                    p.GetYear(_date).ToString(), 
                    p.GetMonth(_date).ToString("00"),
                    p.GetDayOfMonth(_date).ToString("00"));

    return sp;
}
```

since you have saved you datetime as DateTime in database, in your where statement simply check with the datetime value, I mean

```
.Where(i => i.Date >= datenow.Value);
```

Comment: Error 1 Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.

Comment: change this line of your code `Miladi2Shamsi(o.Date),` to `SDate = Miladi2Shamsi(o.Date),`

Comment: i have now 2 error error 1 Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.DateTime?' to 'System.DateTime'

Comment: error 2 Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'accpo.Forms.chek.Chek_daryafti_kh.Miladi2Shamsi(System.DateTime)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: It says, o.Date is not of type DateTime, What is your datatype in sql for your datetimes?

Comment: datatype in sql is date and i save it miladi but i wana when get date show me shamsi i send it to datagrid and stimoulsoft for get report

Comment: For being sure about the function Calli it like this somewhere else 'var s = Miladi2Shamsi(DateTime.Now);' it should work fine, then put your mouse on o.Date and see the data type to be sure that it is DateTime, Janne man yekam bekaresh bendaz rafe khatash kare sakhti nist :)

Comment: thanks man (be khoda be kare hamechi ok hast man ham chek kardam ghablan nemidonam moshkel kojast kolan gir karde mamnon j dadid)

Comment: Did you check o.Date type?

Comment: If you want to get rid of all this code read this article carefully:http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/256104/Using-Custom-Culture-Approach-to-Fix-Persian-Cutur 
By this method you don't need to any other function all dates will show in Persian when you convert them to string.

Comment: Also this link: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/249538/What-s-wrong-with-Persian-culture-in-Net

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use c# in a SQL-2-Linq Expression before materializing.

I.e. add a .ToList() and then .Where(xxxx)

Anyway this will download all rows to the server before filtering and can be slow for big data.